# Add folder as menu to Gnome panel

Tags: panel, menu, gnome-classic

I would like to add a folder to a Gnome panel (Gnome Fallback on ubuntu 12.04). In Windows this can be accomplished by right-clicking the taskbar, selecting "New toolbar", and browsing for a folder. I would like the same functionality in ubuntu. When I click on an icon in the panel, I should get something that looks like the "Applications" menu, but with the content of a specific folder instead.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This [useful](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/8/places-status-indicator/) extension provided you an option to add places to gnome panel.

Also check out other extensions at the main [site](https://extensions.gnome.org/).

Comment: It is for gnome-shell, not for gnome-panel